# Angular: How to make a content editable div's placeholder persist until only when something is typed

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, contenteditable

I have a content editable div in [my angular app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pndmep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that has `attr-placeholder`. I am trying to make it in a way that the placeholder disappears only when something is typed. Right now it disappears when the div is in focus.

1. How to make the content editable div's placeholder persist until only when something is typed?
2. How can I solve the issue of having to click twice on the input box so that I can type?
3. How can I make that the content editable div input is in focus by default when you visit the page?

[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pndmep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of the code I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found an answer to my first two questions. I find that when I as a question it helps me understand my problem more.

The issue was with the css file I changed the part below:

```
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:attr(placeholder);
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

to :

```
[contentEditable=true]:empty:before{
  content:attr(placeholder);
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

I removed the `:not(:focus)` part and it now works. For the third question:

> 3. How can I make that the content editable div input is in focus by default when you visit the page?

I will update it once I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've already found solution for first 2 questions by using pseudo class selectors.

For the Third question, You can use a little bit of JavaScript inside of your `ngOnInit()` -

```
ngOnInit(){
var editableContent = document.getElementById('editableContent');
editableContent.focus();
}
```

Here you need to set the id as `editableContent` for the div element.